# gcloud app engine - 502 Bad Gateway server error

Tags: python, html, flask, google-app-engine, gcloud

After I successfully deploy my gcloud app I am unable to run it in a web browser.

The error that comes up is "502 Bad Gateway
nginx" when I try opening it in my browser with gcloud app browse

This is how I am navigating between pages on my app.py file:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    # If you're just opening your home page
    if request.method == "GET":
       return render_template('index.html')
    # If you submitted one of the forms
    elif request.method == "POST":
       if request.values.get("action1", None) == 'Calculator':
           return render_template('/densitycalc.html')
       elif request.values.get("action2", None) == 'Linear Feet':
           return render_template('/linearFeet.html')
       elif request.values.get("action3", None) == 'Insurance':
           return render_template('insurance.html')
       elif request.values.get("action4", None) == 'Home':
           return render_template('index.html')
```

On each HTML page this is how I am navigating back to the index page below:

```
<head>
    <h1>"{name of page}"</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/" class="fcMenuBar">
        <input type="submit" name="{corresponding page name}" value="{corresponding page value}">
    </form>
</head>
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python38
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

Am I looking in the correct places to identify the error? Or is there another file I am missing?

Comment: Are you getting the error when you try to load your Apps' home page? Are you trying to run a query when the module ```app.py``` is loaded? If so, include the query in your OP

Comment: @NoCommandLine After I finished deploying the app, I run "gcloud app browse" on the command line causes the error, my home page never pulls up. After running it this morning, I'm now getting a "502 Bad Gateway nginx" error.

Comment: Are you trying to run a query when the module app.py is loaded? If so, include the query in your OP

Comment: @NoCommandLine Negative, there are no queries being ran anywhere in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code is currently written, it gives the impression that the attributes - action1, action2, action3, action4 always exists but that doesn't seem to be true from your html page.

Change your code to

```
# If you're just opening your home page
if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template('index.html')

# If you submitted one of the forms
elif request.method == "POST":
    if request.values.get("action", None) == 'Calculator':
        return render_template('/densitycalc.html')
    elif request.values.get("action2", None) == 'Linear Feet':
        return render_template('/linearFeet.html')
    elif request.values.get("action3", None) == 'Insurance':
        return render_template('insurance.html')
    elif request.values.get("action4", None) == 'Home':
        return render_template('index.html')
```

By using `request.values.get("action", None)`, you handle the situation where the attribute 'action' doesn't exist (if the attribute doesn't exist, it gets a default value of None)

#### **Updates** (because you now have a different error)

Your post talks about `app.py` but your app.yaml file has an `entrypoint` which uses `main:app`.

If you don't actually have a `main.py` file which is importing `app.py` and in which the `app` object is being created, then you  should either rename `app.py` to `main.py` or you update entrypoint to refer to `app:app` (I wouldn't advise on this latter option cos your file now has same name as the `app` object)

If you're wondering why the above isn't an issue in Dev but is an issue in Production - the error will only occur in local if you run your app with `dev_appserver.py` which will mimic Google's production server. If you don't run in local with `dev_appserver.py`, then your local env is not making use of `app.yaml` which means it isn't using your `entrypoint` parameter.

Comment: I went back and added your suggestions to my code in my original question (works perfectly on local ). Also added my app.yaml and requirements.txt files. Still getting a "502 Bad Gateway \n
nginx" error. After I complete deployment, then try to open in browser.

Comment: Can you confirm - the error you get after you updated your original code to mine is different from the error you originally posted, right?

Comment: Correct, it started as a 500 server error, now it is a 502 Bad Gateway error.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you still have the issue, make sure your App is following the correct format. Look at sample code from Google https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/main/appengine/standard_python3 or you can use templates from our App - https://nocommandline.com

Comment: Thank you! It was the name of the file. Changed it to "main.py" and removed the entrypoint from my app.yaml file.

Comment: FYI - Since you no longer have ```entrypoint``` in your ```app.yaml``` file, you don't actually have to include ```gunicorn``` as a requirement (having it won't cause any issues either). Google will automatically add it when your App is started up in Production. gunicorn is only explicitly required in requirements.txt when you have an entrypoint.